# Graphs - Browser issue in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, d3.js

i have 3 divs with 3 different ids. In each div i have to place a graph. In firefox it works fine. But in safari i'm getting all the 3 graphs in 1 div, like this:

[image]

I have 3 independent js files for each graph. In html, i'm loading all these graphs in this way:

```
    <script src="js/vendor/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/barChart.js"></script>

    <script src="js/multilineChart.js"></script>

    <script src="js/overviewLineChart.js"></script>
```

It is loading all the graphs in the last script's div.
What is the problem here? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you make a demo here http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: It seems that your all div's are beneath one another,
Try to correctly position your div

Comment: divs are in perfect position.

Comment: No it seems to be not, that why it has cross browser issue,
It is rendered correctly in one, but incorrectly in other.

Comment: put borders on every div with different color, and you will see their position. they are overlapping.

Comment: i have 3 independent divs . 1 in 1 page and the other 2 in different page. The border which i have given for that div is in correct position. The svg which i'm appending is appending to the last div alone.

Comment: Can you provide the HTML used to define the divs and the javascript that appends the graphs to the divs? Without that, we can only guess at what might be happening.

Comment: I found myself :) I have used the same variable name in all charts file for appending the svg. Thanks :)